# Why TkInter doesn't stop running after a Unhandled Exception?

Tags: python, tkinter, exception, callback, raise

Take the bellow code:

```
from tkinter import *

def Raise():
    raise


Window = Tk()
Window.geometry("200x100")

# Raise()

Raise1 = Button(Window,text="Raise", command=Raise)
Raise1.pack()

Window.mainloop()
```

Follow me here:

## Calling Raise() directly:

If the #comment from Raise() is removed, it calls the Raise() function, which in turn, raises an Unhandled Exception that stops the program as I expected.

The message that appears is something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-71427e5db6ac> in <module>
      8 Window.geometry("200x100")
      9 
---> 10 Raise()
     11 
     12 Raise1 = Button(Window,text="Raise", command=Raise)

<ipython-input-1-71427e5db6ac> in Raise()
      2 
      3 def Raise():
----> 4     raise
      5 
      6 

RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise
```

## Calling Raise() through a tkinter button:

But if Raise1 button is clicked, although the same function is called something different happens.
This time Python shows a error message in the console, but Tkinter keeps running. Not what I was expecting.

The message that appears now is different, is something like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-1-1fb7f05e6ef7>", line 4, in Raise
    raise
RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise
```

Since the button triggers the same function as the direct call, shouldn't the behavior to be the same?

Can somebody tell why this happens, and how we are supposed to handle this?

Comment: it wouldn't be user friendly to exit the GUI, how you handle it depends on the exception

Comment: In the previous version of the question I've provided a poor exemple, take a look now.

Comment: you need to raise some exception not just use a plain `raise`, e.g. `raise Exception("exception message")`